# Why do Dto properties return results and Entity properties return null

Tags: spring

My project structure following

ListMusEntity class

```
package software.vn.musicprj.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "list_music", schema = "ktpm", catalog = "")
public class ListMusicEntity {
    private Integer id;
    private String instrumentName;
    private String musicType;
    private byte[] audio;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "instrument_name")
    public String getInstrumentName() {
        return instrumentName;
    }

    public void setInstrumentName(String instrumentName) {
        this.instrumentName = instrumentName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "music_type")
    public String getMusicType() {
        return musicType;
    }

    public void setMusicType(String musicType) {
        this.musicType = musicType;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "audio")
    public byte[] getAudio() {
        return audio;
    }

    public void setAudio(byte[] audio) {
        this.audio = audio;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ListMusicEntity that = (ListMusicEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id) &&
                Objects.equals(instrumentName, that.instrumentName) &&
                Objects.equals(musicType, that.musicType) &&
                Arrays.equals(audio, that.audio);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = Objects.hash(id, instrumentName, musicType);
        result = 31 * result + Arrays.hashCode(audio);
        return result;
    }
}
```

ListDto class

```
package software.vn.musicprj.dto;

        import lombok.Data;
        import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;


@Data
public class ListDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String instrumentName;
    private String musicType;
    private MultipartFile audio;

}
```

ListController class

```
package software.vn.musicprj.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
import software.vn.musicprj.dto.ListDto;
import software.vn.musicprj.entities.ListMusicEntity;
import software.vn.musicprj.service.ListService;
import software.vn.musicprj.utils.FileUtils;
import software.vn.musicprj.utils.ListDtoToListMusicEntityConverter;

import javax.validation.Path;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/music/backend/track")
public class ListController {
    @Autowired
    ListService listService;

    @GetMapping("list")
    public String list(Model model, @RequestParam(name = "name", required = false) String name) {
        Object obj = null;
        if (name == null) {
            obj = listService.findAll();
        } else {
            // handle the case where the name parameter is not null
        }
        model.addAttribute("title", name);
        model.addAttribute("list", obj);
        return "/jsp/music_list.jsp";
    }

    @GetMapping("upload")
    public String create(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Tạo bài nhạc mới");
        model.addAttribute("listDto", new ListDto());
        return "/jsp/create_list.jsp";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "save", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public String save(@Valid ListDto listDto, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            MultipartFile audioFile = listDto.getAudio();
            if (audioFile != null && !audioFile.isEmpty()) {
                byte[] audioBytes = FileUtils.saveFileFromMultiPartFile(audioFile);
                listDto.setAudio(audioFile);
            }
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", listService.save(listDto,audioFile));
        }
        return "redirect:/music/backend/track/list";
    }

}
```

ListService class

```
package software.vn.musicprj.service;

        import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
        import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
        import software.vn.musicprj.dto.ListDto;
        import software.vn.musicprj.entities.ListMusicEntity;
        import software.vn.musicprj.repository.ListRepository;

        import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ListService {
    private static final String SOLO_FLAG = "solo";
    private static final String DUET_FLAG = "duet";

    @Autowired
    ListRepository listRepository;
    public List<ListMusicEntity>findAll(){
        return listRepository.findAll();
    }
    public List<ListMusicEntity> findSoloTracks() {
        return listRepository.findAllByMusicType(SOLO_FLAG);
    }

    public List<ListMusicEntity> findDuetTracks() {
        return listRepository.findAllByMusicType(DUET_FLAG);
    }

    public String save(ListDto listDto, MultipartFile audioFile){
        ListMusicEntity listMusicEntity = new ListMusicEntity();

        BeanUtils.copyProperties(listDto, listMusicEntity);
        listRepository.save(listMusicEntity);
        return "Tạo mới bài nhạc hiệu thành công";
    }
//
//    public ListMusicEntity findById(Integer id){
//        return listRepository.findById(id).get();
//    }
//
//    public String deleteById(Integer id){
//        listRepository.deleteById(id);
//        return "Xóa bài nhạc thành công";
//    }
}
```

FIleUtils class

```
package software.vn.musicprj.utils;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class FileUtils {
    private static final String FOLDER_MEDIA = "D:/opt/music_audio/";

    public static byte[] saveFileFromMultiPartFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
        if (multipartFile == null || multipartFile.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        String nameFile = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
        File file = new File(FOLDER_MEDIA + File.separator + nameFile);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        multipartFile.transferTo(file);

        return Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
    }
}
```

When I debug , the Dto properties return the value I entered , and the Entity returns null ,Attributes in the database of my audio set to Longblob . I tried my best, but the documentation on the internet about uploading files as binary is too little ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;